# Highlight a changed value in *ngFor

Tags: angular

I'm trying to highlight a value when it changes inside an `*ngFor` to notify a user. So far I have managed to do the following

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-zhywqy

The `ngFor` is populated by a json object called `marks`. When the user clicks the update button, `changedMarks` is loaded and I do a `.find` and update `marks` with any objects that have changed values. What I would like to do is apply a style called `.updated` to the `li` of the changed value:

```
<ul *ngFor="let mark of marks;" >
   <li>{{ mark.type }}</li>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let outcome of mark.Outcomes;  let i = index"> // add update style here if changed
      {{ outcome.name }} - {{ outcome.value }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</ul>

<button (click)="changeMarks()">Update</button>
```

Comment: What I would do is make a property for `newMark.selected = true` in the function changedMarks. And then in the html `[ngClass]="{'highlight': outcome.selected === true"`. Where Highlight would be your css class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a property for `newMark.selected = true` in the function changedMarks.

And then in the html `[ngClass]="{'highlight': outcome.selected === true"`. Where Highlight would be your css class.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve your problem is using `ngFor trackBy` with your `*ngFor` block.
To learn about `ngFor trackBy`, see this video from YouTube:

[Angular ngFor trackBy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dEIg-PR4Tew&list=PL6n9fhu94yhWqGD8BuKuX-VTKqlNBj-m6&index=17)

Then, you can use style binding or class binding to bind any style to it.
To learn about style/class binding, check out:

Angular Official Documentation => [Attribute, class & style binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#attribute-class-and-style-bindings)

Class Binding Video Tutorial => [Class binding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ea_6MIIVK0Y&list=PL6n9fhu94yhWqGD8BuKuX-VTKqlNBj-m6&index=12)

Style Binding Video Tutorial => [Style binding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dIn7E1P5boE&list=PL6n9fhu94yhWqGD8BuKuX-VTKqlNBj-m6&index=13)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I watched and read some of this and have made the changes here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-zhywqy But I still do understand how to add the css class with trackBy.

Comment: Good to know it was helpful, you can update this answer as commented by @Swoox , and adopted by you, to take it out of unanswered stack questions.

Comment: Please do not perform hostile rollbacks Abhishek. Mutual editing is part of the Stack Overflow model, and accepting that is a condition of posting here.

Comment: @halfer Your editing doesn't add anything informational to the post. SO, what's the point of doing it at random posts. Everyone has their way of putting answers in their reffered way, plus the post was already so clear. How does removing an arrow makes it better?

Comment: @halfer Also, I have many posts with the same notion of writing. So, do all of them are wrong as per StackOverflow Community. Please, stop doing random and unnecessary edits in every other post.

Comment: I'm happy to get feedback from people I edit, but not all feedback is valid. In particular an insistence on "hey this is just my style" to excuse misspellings, general pleading, incorrect case etc. is not generally accepted. I do give way for reasonable objections, and I strive to be as amenable as I can, but not in this case, sorry.